# How to solve redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage in React.js

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, server-side-rendering, redux-saga

My React Application works fine in Client-side rendering.I'm trying to Implement Server-side rendering in my app for SEO purposes.

when I run server.js file I got an error.

How can I solve this issue?
**Server.js**

```
    import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

const PORT = 8080;
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();
app.use(express.json());

const serverRenderer = (req, res, next) => {
    const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
<Provider store={store}>
<PresistGate presist={presist}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
            <App />
        </StaticRouter>
</PresistGate >
</Provider>
    );
    fs.readFile(path.resolve('../dist/index.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('An error occurred');
        }
        return res.send(data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${content}</div>`));
    });
};
router.use('*', serverRenderer);

router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist'), { maxAge: '30d' }));

// tell the app to use the above rules
app.use(router);

// app.use(express.static('./build'))
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`SSR running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That error happens because you want to create the localstorage object on the server side, so that's the reason for warning.

I did the following to solve.

```js
import createWebStorage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage';
const createNoopStorage = () => {
   return {
      getItem(_key: any) {
         return Promise.resolve(null);
      },
      setItem(_key: any, value: any) {
         return Promise.resolve(value);
      },
      removeItem(_key: any) {
         return Promise.resolve();
      },
   };
};
const storage = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? createWebStorage('local') : createNoopStorage();


const reducers = combineReducers({
   YourReducers:xxxx.reducer
 });

const persistConfig = {
   key: 'root',
   storage //here we will put the storage variable that we created above
};
.... and here all the rest of your configuration...
```

Comment: Above solution just disappeard the error. But local storage still not updating values. Not sure what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late to answer but,

In case of NextJs, the issue is solved by using storage conditionally based on it is **client side** or **server side** for persisting the states.
As for the matter of fact the **'window is not defined on server side'**.

Example code :

```
const isClient = typeof window !== "undefined";

let mainReducer;
if (isClient) {
 const { persistReducer } = require("redux-persist");
 const storage = require("redux-persist/lib/storage").default;

 const rootPersistConfig = {
   key: "root",
   storage: storage,
   blacklist: ["countries"],
 };

 const countriesPersistConfig = {
   key: "countries",
   storage: storage,
   whitelist: ["countriesList"],
 };

 /* COMBINE REDUCERS */
 const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
   countries: persistReducer(countriesPersistConfig, countries),
 });

 mainReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, combinedReducers);
} else {
 mainReducer = combineReducers({
   countries,
 });
}
```

If it still doesn't solve the problem. Try reading through this thread - [using-redux-with-redux-persist-with-server-side-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173999/using-redux-with-redux-persist-with-server-side-rendering)

Thank you.